# Plugin: How to insert new method in existing PHP class?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, intellij-14, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to create a IntelliJ plugin (mostly for learning purposes). My aim is that by pressing a keyboard shortcut the plugin will generate a corresponding PHP unit test method stub in the test file.

So let's say `Db.php` is open, the upon pressing `Ctrl+Shift+U` the plugin will create a unit test stub in `DbTest.php`.

So far I've figured out how to get the method name at cursor and how to locate the corresponding Unit test file (i.e. `Db` => `DbTest`) as `PsiFile`.

```
PsiFile[] search = FilenameIndex.getFilesByName(project, testFileName, scope); //scope is the test directory
PsiFile testFile = search[0];
```

What I cannot figure out is **how to insert the *generated* new method stub this in `testFile` and then save the changes?**

P.S. I see there exists a `createMethodFromText` function but how do I get the PsiClass from PsiFile? Also how do I save the changes?

Answer (score 1):

There're just a few simple steps.

1. Find `PhpClass` you want to insert a new method in. As you already have `PsiFile` you can either traverse a tree manually or use `PhpElementVisitor`.

   1.1. To travers a tree manually you can use `PsiTreeUtil#findChildOfType` method. In your case you'll need to find `GroupStatement` first, then the class you need.

   1.2. Invoke `PsiElement#accept` method (`PsiFile` is an instance of `PsiElement`) provided with `PhpElementVisitor` with overridden `#visitPhpGroupStatement` and `#visitPhpClass` methods.
2. Use `PhpPsiElementFactory#createMethod` to create the new method from text. Note that this class isn't a part of the public API, so theoretically it can be easily changed/moved/removed/whatever in the future.
3. Use `PsiElement#add` (`PhpClass` is also an instance of `PsiElement`) to insert the method into the class.

That's all. You don't need to explicitly save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me in the end. Thanks everyone for the help

```
for (int i = 0; i < found.getTextLength(); i++) {
    PsiElement ele = found.findElementAt(i);
    PhpClass phpClass = PsiTreeUtil.getParentOfType(ele, PhpClass.class);

    if (phpClass != null) {
        Method methodExists = findMethod(phpClass, methodName);

        if (methodExists == null) {
            new WriteCommandAction.Simple(phpClass.getProject(), phpClass.getContainingFile()) {
                @Override
                protected void run() throws Throwable {
                    PsiElement brace = phpClass.getLastChild();

                    if (brace != null) {
                        Method method = PhpPsiElementFactory.createMethod(phpClass.getProject(), "public function " + methodName + "() {\n\n}");
                        CodeStyleManager styleManager = CodeStyleManager.getInstance(getProject());
                        styleManager.reformat(method);
                        PsiElement newMethod = phpClass.addBefore(method, brace);
                        PsiNavigateUtil.navigate(newMethod);
                    }
                }
            }.execute();
        } else {
            PsiNavigateUtil.navigate(methodExists);
        }

        break;
    }
}
```